# how to implement automatic update feature in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I am developing an iPhone app. It has an option called automatic update. it can be updated automatically once in a week/month/6 months. Could you please let me know How can I invoke my desired method based on this setting even my app was not opened by the user?

Answer (score 4):

You can't, the user will need to open the app, there is no way to schedule update routines.

You could inform the user that he/she need to update with an `UILocalNotification`, but I would suggest only to update your app when the users starts it.

Answer (score 0):

It's against apples rules to push an updated app within your app. You have to resubmit to the app store.

Comment: That depends, if the update exists of new data (like reading a feed) then there is not problem. If you want to update any part of your app, like add a new screen then yes you will have to submit a new version to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is that increase badge count of application icon on receiving notification from UIlocalNotification.

when user open application check the application badge count if it is more than zero  apply your logic to update application.

else there will be no update popup to client.